# ffmpeg, put 5000 trimmed inputs and filter complex into file?

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, video

I have a huge monolithic ffmpeg command and unfortunately I am not able to run it because "the command line is too long." I'm on Windows 10. The exact input command and output can be seen below:

```
ffmpeg -ss "00:00:03" -to 00:00:29 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\nelson-5784640.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5112050.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "transformed\rain\kelly-lacy-9468768.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3925550.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_3999405.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\taryn-elliott-8549483.mp4" -ss 00:00:11 -to 00:00:37 -i "transformed\rain\anni-a-5285672.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "transformed\rain\jill-burrow-7681520.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\bokor-marketing-10301571.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4631227.mp4" -ss 00:00:10 -to 00:00:36 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5108686.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4742117.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:18 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\missdeena-9934612.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4420218.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5108686.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 4625.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4742117.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919507.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 1484703.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:08 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816406.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4757483.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\hemanth-k-m-5487781.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\Videos 2059694.mp4" -ss 00:00:15 -to 00:00:41 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 4618.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4472112.mp4" -ss 00:00:23 -to 00:00:49 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 1774955.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5025886.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\francesco-ungaro-5227362.mp4" -ss 00:00:07 -to 00:00:33 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\atypeek-dgn-7043616.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:24 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919509.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\taryn-elliott-8549483.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816627.mp4" -ss 00:00:14 -to 00:00:40 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4184080.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5156396.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4779388.mp4" -ss 00:00:07 -to 00:00:33 -i "transformed\rain\punit-kumar-6040646.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\ratikanta-mallick-5327689.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5156396.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\anastasia-shuraeva-7663345.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5155678.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4933583.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4171515.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:25 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3999435.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\anastasia-shuraeva-7663145.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4112833.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\Videos 2491284.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\marc-onana-6070850.mp4" -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:31 -i "transformed\rain\anni-a-5285672.mp4" -ss 00:01:23 -to 00:01:49 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 1841455.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4198961.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4198961.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\marc-onana-6070850.mp4" -ss 00:00:29 -to 00:00:55 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\nelson-5784640.mp4" -ss 00:00:18 -to 00:00:44 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4306829.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5025886.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\taryn-elliott-8549416.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4112833.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4472112.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4779388.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\video.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\nelson-5843699.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\anastasia-shuraeva-7663345.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:17 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4059704.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:24 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919509.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\taryn-elliott-8549416.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\francesco-ungaro-5227362.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\ivan-khmelyuk-9345855.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\khanhhoangminh-10761873.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4757483.mp4" -ss 00:00:08 -to 00:00:34 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\video (1).mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\vânia-morena-oliver-gustavo-9778487.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\video.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4272853.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4272853.mp4" -ss 00:00:18 -to 00:00:44 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4306829.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3925550.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\kelly-lacy-9632864.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_5155678.mp4" -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:31 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\atypeek-dgn-7043616.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4933583.mp4" -ss 00:01:18 -to 00:01:44 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 1841455.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 1484703.mp4" -ss 00:00:24 -to 00:00:50 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\base_video.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4420218.mp4" -ss 00:00:01 -to 00:00:27 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4184080.mp4" -ss 00:00:31 -to 00:00:57 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\okayama-candle-yutoridx-6445790.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4919507.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4171515.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\nelson-5843699.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:25 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3999435.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\kelly-lacy-9632864.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 4618.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "transformed\rain\jill-burrow-7681520.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_5112050.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\shashank-kumar-5526255.mp4" -ss 00:00:24 -to 00:00:50 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 1774955.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\shashank-kumar-5526255.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_3999405.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\jill-burrow-7681526.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\anastasia-shuraeva-7663145.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\sebastián-muriel-7843122.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:23 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\jill-burrow-7681526.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\Videos 4625.mp4" -ss 00:00:03 -to 00:00:29 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\base_video.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:20 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\production ID_4631227.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:19 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\sebastián-muriel-7843122.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:14 -i "transformed\rain\Videos 2491284.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:11 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816627.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:18 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\missdeena-9934612.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:08 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_3816406.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:17 -i "transformed\rain\production ID_4059704.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\khanhhoangminh-10761873.mp4" -ss 00:00:02 -to 00:00:28 -i "transformed\rain\kelly-lacy-9468768.mp4" -ss 00:00:04 -to 00:00:30 -i "transformed\rain\bokor-marketing-10301571.mp4" -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:31 -i "transformed\rain\punit-kumar-6040646.mp4" -ss 00:00:13 -to 00:00:39 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\video (1).mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\vânia-morena-oliver-gustavo-9778487.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:15 -i "transformed\rain\ivan-khmelyuk-9345855.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:10 -i "transformed\rain\Videos 2059694.mp4" -ss 00:00:06 -to 00:00:32 -i "F:\MusicGen\visual\transformed\rain - desaturated\okayama-candle-yutoridx-6445790.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:16 -i "transformed\rain\hemanth-k-m-5487781.mp4" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:26 -i "transformed\rain\ratikanta-mallick-5327689.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=23:duration=3[1v];[1v][2:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=43:duration=3[2v];[2v][3:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=66:duration=3[3v];[3v][4:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=82:duration=3[4v];[4v][5:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=105:duration=3[5v];[5v][6:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=112:duration=3[6v];[6v][7:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=135:duration=3[7v];[7v][8:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=158:duration=3[8v];[8v][9:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=181:duration=3[9v];[9v][10:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=198:duration=3[10v];[10v][11:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=221:duration=3[11v];[11v][12:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=228:duration=3[12v];[12v][13:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=243:duration=3[13v];[13v][14:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=266:duration=3[14v];[14v][15:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=289:duration=3[15v];[15v][16:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=296:duration=3[16v];[16v][17:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=303:duration=3[17v];[17v][18:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=326:duration=3[18v];[18v][19:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=338:duration=3[19v];[19v][20:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=343:duration=3[20v];[20v][21:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=366:duration=3[21v];[21v][22:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=379:duration=3[22v];[22v][23:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=386:duration=3[23v];[23v][24:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=409:duration=3[24v];[24v][25:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=432:duration=3[25v];[25v][26:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=455:duration=3[26v];[26v][27:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=472:duration=3[27v];[27v][28:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=495:duration=3[28v];[28v][29:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=518:duration=3[29v];[29v][30:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=539:duration=3[30v];[30v][31:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=546:duration=3[31v];[31v][32:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=554:duration=3[32v];[32v][33:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=577:duration=3[33v];[33v][34:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=600:duration=3[34v];[34v][35:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=623:duration=3[35v];[35v][36:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=646:duration=3[36v];[36v][37:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=669:duration=3[37v];[37v][38:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=692:duration=3[38v];[38v][39:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=705:duration=3[39v];[39v][40:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=728:duration=3[40v];[40v][41:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=739:duration=3[41v];[41v][42:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=747:duration=3[42v];[42v][43:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=769:duration=3[43v];[43v][44:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=776:duration=3[44v];[44v][45:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=792:duration=3[45v];[45v][46:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=803:duration=3[46v];[46v][47:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=814:duration=3[47v];[47v][48:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=837:duration=3[48v];[48v][49:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=860:duration=3[49v];[49v][50:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=871:duration=3[50v];[50v][51:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=882:duration=3[51v];[51v][52:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=893:duration=3[52v];[52v][53:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=916:duration=3[53v];[53v][54:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=939:duration=3[54v];[54v][55:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=956:duration=3[55v];[55v][56:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=973:duration=3[56v];[56v][57:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=989:duration=3[57v];[57v][58:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1012:duration=3[58v];[58v][59:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1035:duration=3[59v];[59v][60:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1043:duration=3[60v];[60v][61:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1066:duration=3[61v];[61v][62:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1079:duration=3[62v];[62v][63:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1093:duration=3[63v];[63v][64:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1114:duration=3[64v];[64v][65:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1131:duration=3[65v];[65v][66:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1154:duration=3[66v];[66v][67:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1166:duration=3[67v];[67v][68:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1178:duration=3[68v];[68v][69:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1201:duration=3[69v];[69v][70:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1224:duration=3[70v];[70v][71:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1231:duration=3[71v];[71v][72:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1239:duration=3[72v];[72v][73:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1251:duration=3[73v];[73v][74:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1263:duration=3[74v];[74v][75:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1286:duration=3[75v];[75v][76:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1302:duration=3[76v];[76v][77:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1325:duration=3[77v];[77v][78:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1348:duration=3[78v];[78v][79:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1371:duration=3[79v];[79v][80:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1382:duration=3[80v];[80v][81:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1405:duration=3[81v];[81v][82:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1417:duration=3[82v];[82v][83:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1440:duration=3[83v];[83v][84:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1463:duration=3[84v];[84v][85:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1486:duration=3[85v];[85v][86:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1509:duration=3[86v];[86v][87:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1532:duration=3[87v];[87v][88:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1540:duration=3[88v];[88v][89:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1563:duration=3[89v];[89v][90:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1585:duration=3[90v];[90v][91:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1608:duration=3[91v];[91v][92:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1631:duration=3[92v];[92v][93:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1654:duration=3[93v];[93v][94:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1674:duration=3[94v];[94v][95:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1694:duration=3[95v];[95v][96:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1717:duration=3[96v];[96v][97:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1737:duration=3[97v];[97v][98:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1760:duration=3[98v];[98v][99:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1780:duration=3[99v];[99v][100:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1787:duration=3[100v];[100v][101:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1803:duration=3[101v];[101v][102:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1823:duration=3[102v];[102v][103:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1830:duration=3[103v];[103v][104:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1853:duration=3[104v];[104v][105:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1870:duration=3[105v];[105v][106:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1886:duration=3[106v];[106v][107:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1897:duration=3[107v];[107v][108:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1905:duration=3[108v];[108v][109:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1920:duration=3[109v];[109v][110:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1925:duration=3[110v];[110v][111:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1939:duration=3[111v];[111v][112:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1951:duration=3[112v];[112v][113:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1974:duration=3[113v];[113v][114:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=1997:duration=3[114v];[114v][115:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2020:duration=3[115v];[115v][116:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2043:duration=3[116v];[116v][117:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2050:duration=3[117v];[117v][118:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2062:duration=3[118v];[118v][119:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2069:duration=3[119v];[119v][120:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2092:duration=3[120v];[120v][121:v]xfade=transition=fade:offset=2105:duration=3[121v]" -map [121v] -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -c:a aac -q:a 4 -map_metadata -1 output.mp4 -y -hide_banner
The command line is too long.
```

I assume what I will need to do is somehow convert this into a text file that ffmpeg loads instead to avoid the command line being too long. The issue is that I am not sure how to do this with so many inputs and with each input having different random trim times (the `-ss` and `-to` flags).

That example is obviously pretty large since there are so many input files, but all I need would be a small/shorter example to get the picture.

Three questions:

1. Is using a separate text file the way to solve this issue?
2. If so, can I see a small example that incorporates the filter and the trimming of a few inputs?
3. Is there a limit on how many video files can be input into a single ffmpeg command? For example, I intend to do this with up to around five thousand input clips, and I have no idea if that can scale. This example with only 120 was just a short test.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the command exe, but I may suggest the following: 1. Get bash (git bash for instance). 2. Make a shell script where each /path/file/ is put in a variable. ffmpeg can then act upon each $variable. At least this will make it a lot easier to read, and maintain to start with. However, bash has limits too. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354870/bash-command-line-and-input-limit and also this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643777/is-there-any-limit-on-line-length-when-pasting-to-a-terminal-in-linux